# wxPython menu display image after label

Tags: python, menu, wxpython, wxwidgets

Last days working on a python cross-platform project for openWRT gui Application.
It is possible to display image on the right side of menu with wxpython?

```
   def mainMenu(wxMenu):
    TBMENU_RESTORE = wx.NewId()
    TBMENU_CLOSE   = wx.NewId()
    TBMENU_CHANGE  = wx.NewId()
    TBMENU_REMOVE  = wx.NewId()

    menu = wx.Menu()
    menu.Append(1138, "DL: 115,5  |  UL: 85,2")
    menu.Enable(1138, False)
    menu.AppendSeparator()        
    menu.AppendCheckItem(1109,  "tes1")
    menu.AppendCheckItem(1110,  "tes2")
    menu.AppendCheckItem(1111,  "tes3")
    menu.Check(1111, True)
    menu.AppendSeparator()
    menu.Append(wx.NewId(), "Turn Guest Network Off")
    menu.AppendSeparator()
    menu.Append(TBMENU_RESTORE, "Settings")
    menu.Append(TBMENU_CLOSE,   "Quit")
    wxMenu.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DCLICK, wxMenu.MenuOpen)
    wxMenu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, wxMenu.MenuOpen, id=TBMENU_RESTORE)
    wxMenu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, wxMenu.QuitApp, id=TBMENU_CLOSE)     
    item = wx.MenuItem(menu, wx.ID_ANY, "Snake", "This menu has a picture!")
    img = wx.Image('snake32.bmp', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
    item.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))     
    menu.AppendItem(item)
    return menu
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this is not possible with the OS-GUI drawn menus. Maybe you could take a look at https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.flatmenu.html and modify it accordingly.

Comment: @Konstantinos, on the right side of the menu there is a place for the menu shortcut, according to any and all OS guidelines. You can try to use an owner-drawn menu or a flatmenu as suggested by MichaelButscher.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it and i will report back soon.